# The "rake" command gets the error "no such file to load -- rspec/core/rake_task"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using Ubuntu version 12.04.02, Ruby 1.8.7, Gems 1.8.15, trying to do TestFirst.org's Learn Ruby (http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby).

The folder where I store all the files for the course is located on my computer in /home/topher/ruby/learn_ruby-master.

I've followed the instructions to go into the folder labeled 00_hello within the larger folder and create an empty text document called "hello.rb" in the 00_hello folder. Then I go into the terminal, navigate to ~/ruby/learn_ruby-master/00_hello and type:

> rake

First I got this error message:

> (in /home/topher/ruby/learn_ruby-master)
>   rake aborted!
>   undefined method `gem' for main:Object
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I did some searching and found a thread on Stack Overflow where someone recommended deleting the line in the rake file that said:

> gem 'rspec', '~2'

I did so (or rather, commented it out to be on the safe side) and got a different error message on running "rake":

> (in /home/topher/ruby/learn_ruby-master)
>   rake aborted!
>   no such file to load -- rspec/core/rake_task
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

How do I fix this?

Comment: I assume you installed the rspec gem?

Comment: Oh yeah. Rspec v 2.14.5. To me, it looks like what it's telling me is most of rspec is there, but there's a file or folder within it missing.

Comment: how did you install ruby, maybe it lacks rubygems somehow?

Comment: 1.8.7 doesnt come with rubygems by default if i remember correctly. That was changed in 1.9x

Answer (score 2):

That learning project requires [bundler](http://bundler.io/). You know this because at the project's root path there is a file called [Gemfile](https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby/blob/master/Gemfile)

So in order to continue, first install bundler then run `bundle install` then `rake`:

```
$ gem install bundler rubygems-bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri
$ bundle install
$ rake
```

Prefer a newer Ruby version like 2.0.0 rather than 1.8.7. You can use [rvm](http://rvm.io/) to get everything setup for you. As a bonus you won't need to install bunder nor rubygems since they are included since ruby 1.9

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ rvm requirements
$ rvm install 2.0.0
$ rvm use --default 2.0.0
```